# How to keep a persistent widget across Navigator routes?

Tags: flutter

I have a `NavigationDrawer` that on large screens I keep open and fixed on the left side of the screen.
Each route's builder creates a screen as follows:

```dart
Row(children: [
    const CustomDrawer(),
    Expanded(child: scaffold),
])
```

Right now, the drawer is rebuilt on each screen.
This means, among other things, that the scroll state of the drawer is not persisted, and that the drawer is animated together with the rest of the screen (animation slowed down for illustration purposes):

[image: current behaviour animation]

I want the drawer to be persistent across all screens.
This includes that the state (such as the scroll state) be preserved, and that the drawer remains fixed without animation when a new page is pushed.

How do I achieve this?

I've looked into similar situations, but I couldn't find a solution suited for this situation. For example, a custom Navigator allows setting a custom bottom navigation bar, but not a drawer.

Comment: Are you using GoRouter for navigation or which Navigator are you using?

Comment: @pcba-dev I'm using the vanilla Flutter Navigator. I set up my app like `MaterialApp(..., onGenerateRoute: (...) {...}, ...)`.

Answer (score -1):

That is because your `drawer` is inside your `body` of `scaffold`, There is a property of `scaffold` widget named `drawer` and you can put it inside, but there might be an issue, whenever you go to a new page, the drawer will actually close. I believe for web or desktop, it is nice to add a package.

[Side Navigation.](https://pub.dev/packages/side_navigation) Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed, I don't do it that way because I want the drawer to stay open always. It's more of a sidebar in this case.